# Bootstrap model covered by modal backdrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I have simple html page to show bootstrap modal, however when I launch the model -
it gets covered by modal backdrop, 
I checked the z- index of myModal - 1040 and that of modal backdrop is 1030
checked all posts in stackoverflow but none of them solve my issue
please help

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>




    <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade in" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Log in</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="modal-form" id="loginform">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="login" id="username">
                <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="password" id="userpassword">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: "checked all posts in stackoverflow" No you didn't, as that is flat-out impossible. If you list *why/how* each of the posts you did check didn't help, your question would be a lot better; as it is, that statement is just noise.

Comment: Actually I copied lots of modal dialog codes from different websites which were working on their sites. but didn't for me. I played with it for some time and got it working. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a few things, which are:

- the `<div class="modal-dialog">`
- the `<div class="modal-content">`

You also added some unecessary things which are:

- the `hide` class on the `<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in" aria-hidden="true">`
- the `in` class on the `<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in" aria-hidden="true">`

Your working code will look like this:

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Log in</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="modal-form" id="loginform">
          <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="login" id="username">
          <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="password" id="userpassword">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fL9qth89/5/) to show it in a working environment.

To read everything about the modal, please check [this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, I realized my mistakes and made it working which is what you are suggesting

Comment: @IraDev no problem at all, please do not forget to mark the answer you find most useful and correct as "the answer" to help others quickly find the solution to a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `hide` class from your modal.

[JSFdiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trch0Lt6/)

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Log in</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form class="modal-form" id="loginform">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="login" id="username">
      <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="password" id="userpassword">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
  </div>
</div>
```